# sql missing date query

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

Having a table with these records:

```
01-JAN-15 10:00
01-JAN-15 11:00
01-JAN-15 13:00
01-JAN-15 14:00
01-JAN-15 15:00
01-JAN-15 18:00
01-JAN-15 19:00
```

It's 1h resolution, so in my example 12:00, 16:00 and, 17:00 are missing.

I would like to create an SQL query that returns something like this (missing hour start, and duration):

```
01-JAN-15 12:00, 01:00
01-JAN)15 16:00, 02:00
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: Please edit your question and show what the columns and types are.  It is unclear how many different columns your data represents.

Comment: Just looking for the edit button.... :) but you were faster ! thanks

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your values are `datetime` values, then you can do something like this:

```
select t.*, 
       datediff(hour, datetimecol, next_datetimecol)
from (select t.*, 
             lead(datetimecol) over (order by datetimecol) as next_datetime
      from t
     ) t
where next_datetimecol is not null and
      dateadd(hour, 1, datetimecol) < next_datetimecol;
```

Depending on your data types and the precision, this might not work exactly.  But the idea is basically the same . . . use `lead()` to get the next value and do some comparisons.

Comment: Thank so much, yes value are datetime. About the precision, the other field (min, sec, milli...) are all always zero in my case.

Comment: in my case I would like two records, but for each a second value should contains the gap duration

Comment: I'm using SQL 2008R2, looks like LEAD is only available in 2012 unfortunatly.